# Using object field as function parameter other field

Tags: c#

It is possible using new object field as function parameter other field (in this same object initialization)?

```
List<Reservations> reservations = new List<Reservations>()
 {
  new Reservations{title="Grooming", className=checkColor(title)},
 };

public string checkColor(string title)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: yes you can do it

Comment: I don't think so. you have to use className=checkColor("Grooming") Why you just have not checked it  immedialtely instead of waisting time of another people?

Comment: No, you cannot reference an object from within that object’s object initializer. You should consider using a constructor or a factory method instead if you need to run additional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible with the current design of your code. The reason is, you can not reference 1 field of the object in another field before the object is fully constructed. That is same as why we can't use 1 field value in another while declaring as class level varibales.

However, there are ways you can achieve, what you want to.

**Option 1:**

```
const string titleText = "Grooming";
List<Reservations> reservations = new List<Reservations>()
{
    new Reservations{title=titleText, className=checkColor(titleText)},
};

private static string checkColor(string title)
{
 ...
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
    class Consumer
    {
        List<Reservations> reservations = new List<Reservations>()
        {
            new Reservations{title="Grooming"}
        };
    }

    class Reservations
    {
        string _title;

        public string title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }

            set
            {
                _title = value;
                className = checkColor(title);
            }
        }

        public string className;

        private string checkColor(string title)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```